# How to set font to Arial throughout the entire document?

Tags: fonts

In preamble, I have:

```
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{arial}
```

but it doesn't work.

How do I set my font to Arial throughout the entire document?

**UPDATE:**

In short, both answers work.

It really depends on the environment. If using LaTeX and don't mind using a cloned font then choose Herbert's answer. If using XeLaTex and want to use the authentic font then choose Leo's.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Arial is not installed in TeX Live, I'm not sure about MiKTeX. You can use `helvet` package instead.

```
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

If you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you can use TrueType Arial font installed in your Windows/Mac:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
```

In Ubuntu, Arial can be installed by a Synaptic Package named ttf-mscorefonts-installer.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 and have texlive-full 2009-7 installed. I see XeTeX & LuaTeX installed but your method doesn't work.

Comment: @Level1Coder: Well, Arial is a commercial font. You use Linux, but there's no Arial in linux distribution.

Comment: @Leo: But there is: http://corefonts.sourceforge.net/ The corresponding package is usually named `corefonts`.

Comment: @Level1Coder: Arial is very similar to Helvetica, Arial and Helvetica are both commercial fonts. `helvet` package actually uses Nimbus Sans font (a Helvetica clone); `uarial` uses URW A030 font (an Arial clone). Most cases, `helvet` package will suffie. If you want to use *real* Arial, you must get the TrueType/OpenType font from Windows/Mac and install it in your Linux OS, then use it with XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX.

Comment: +1 to Andrey for mentioning `corefonts`.

After experimentation, I found under Ubuntu Synaptic Package named `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`. After installing this, Leo's answer works!

Changed my mind to use Leo's answer because of the use of authentic fonts from MSCoreFonts.  And also because of frequent use of Chinese, XeLaTex seems to be the best tool to handle Chinese characters. (Was planning to settle with PDFLaTeX to create intermixing English/Chinese documents)

Comment: I had read that ´fontspec´ shouldn't use with Koma classes e.g. scrbook

Comment: What if you compile with pdfLaTeX?

Answer (score 41):

Use it this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{uarial}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

but you must have installed the package called `uarial` (not arial) beforehand. If you do not have this package then install it with `sudo getnonfreefonts --sys -a`, which will install all available non-free fonts into your system (more info [here](http://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/)). The script was part of TeXLive until the 2009 version. Ubuntu users should have it already installed.

Comment: `uarial`, [`urw-arial`](http://ctan.org/pkg/urw-arial) in `urw` bundle is not available in TeX Live and MiKTeX, it is necessary to install the font package manually. I guess it would be a little difficult for newbies.

Comment: run `sudo getnonfreefonts-sys` and they will be available ...

Comment: Downloaded all fonts with this command `sudo getnonfreefonts-sys -a` Arial is rendering in my PDF now, awesome and thanks!

Comment: A quick 2015 follow up on @Leo Liu's comment: this solution worked for me in `RStudio`compiling with `pdfLaTeX` without the need to install any packages manually. Thanks for this answer!

Comment: I tried `\usepackage{uarial}` in MiKTeX and it was installed automatically (with the usual prompt).

Comment: I'm a newbie in Ubuntu, but I could follow the installation steps as stated in https://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/

Comment: True, it changed with TL 2016, if I am right.

Comment: 10 years later, and this worked for me! Great solution!

Answer (score 5):

I struggled with this forever. Finally found an [article](http://cambio.name/personal/content/how-use-arial-font-latex) that showed me these two lines of code:

```
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv} % Arial
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv} % Arial
```

Only thing that worked for me, after hours of struggling with luatex and xelatex.

This answer only loads a Helvetica clone, not true Arial. If you need **true** Arial for whatever reason this won't work.

Comment: Note that these instructions load a Helvetica clone, *not* true Arial. Because Arial is itself a clone of Helvetica, the result may be good enough for *your* requirements. Your answer should make clear(er), though, that it answers the OP's query only approximately, not exactly.

Comment: Hmm, good call. I didn't think of that!

Comment: dead link http://cambio.name/personal/content/how-use-arial-font-latex

Comment: Good enough for me. How dare SSHRC (a Canadian gov't research funding agency) demand Arial font if it's not free and open?!