# Change font of nomenclature (nomencl)

Tags: fonts, nomenclature

I am strying to change the font of my abbreviations list `\printnomenclature` ([nomencl.sty](http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/nomencl.pdf)) so I can have the abbreviations in bold (my main font lacks a bold version). I've tried several things, but I just can't get it to work. The font changes to default, and italics in the definitions are lost for some weird reason.

```
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List}
\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{\textbf{#1}} %bold abbreviations
\printnomenclature
\input{ABC}
```

I've tried this with no luck:

```
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List}
\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{\textbf{#1}} %bold abbreviations
{\fontfamily{Arial}\selectfont\printnomenclature}
\input{ABC}
```

Also this:

```
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List}
\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{{\fontfamily{Arial Bold}\selectfont{#1}}} %bold abbreviations
\printnomenclature
\input{ABC}
```

Comment: If you add a [minimal but complete working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem you'll improve your chances of getting an answer significantly. We are not able to guess which main font you use nor how you load it. A MWE would allow to reproduce the problem and hopefully show both the reason for the problem and a possible way out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Helvetica instead with

```
\usepackage{helvet}
```

Then,

```
\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont \textbf{#1}}} %bold Helvetica
```

should work.

The issues of using really Arial are described here: [How to set font to Arial throughout the entire document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23957/21591)

Comment: I see. I really don't want to use Arial, but Gentium Basic. I just tried wíth Arial as an example. The issue is the same with Gentium Basic. My main font is Gentium Plus.