# ! LaTeX Error: File `arial.sty' not found

Tags: fonts, errors

i m using following command.

```
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{arial}
```

but getting error message:

! LaTeX Error: File `arial.sty' not found. How can i fix this error.

Regards

Comment: Check out [How to set font to Arial throughout the entire document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23960/22413).  You should be able to find your answer there.

Comment: Helvetica is a much appreciated original typeface. Try `\usepackage{helvet} `.

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be `Arial` or is `Helvetica` okay? If it is okay then use:

```
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

If no, you can use `uarial`, an Arial clone (http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/arial/).

To install:

a) follow http://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/ to install the `getnonfreefonts` script, it works on Windows as well

b) run `getnonfreefonts --all`(installs all URW fonts, run `getnonfreefonts --help` for more details)

c) Use the following in your document:

```
\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

d) If you have `Arial` installed on your computer anyway, you can also use XeTeX/LuaTeX, as described in the mentioned [How to set font to Arial throughout the entire document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23960/7615):

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
```

Comment: I m using c) Use the following in your document:

\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} still output is Times New Roman

Comment: I don't think it's Times New Roman what you get, probably `Computer Modern`. What does the log file say? Create a minimal document where you just print a few words. I did the installation for my answer on Win 7/TeXlive 2012, worked like a charm. If you're on Linux you probably should read the help for `getnonfreefonts` there are some specifics concerning a user-wide resp. system-wide installation.

Comment: I have uploaeded output at http://postimage.org/image/e3g45h7uz/ae3c0d17/ . MWE code:  http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=CHOwM

Comment: The log file might be more interesting. One remark: I did the installation on win 7, so I got no trouble with rights specific issues. Did you check the help, did you `sudo` the commands? What does the log file say about any errors?

Comment: i have uploaded log file but there is no error message. http://www.pastebin.ca/2315480

Comment: But there's a warning, that "ua" was not found and therefore replace by CM (Computer Modern). The UARIAL installation was not complete, please check the installation procedure.