# Using Arial and font size 8.5pt

Tags: fonts

Is there a way to set font arial and font size 8.5pt using TexStudio? Which documentclass can apply font size 8.5pt?

Comment: Texstudio is only the editor. Are you searching for [using Arial with LaTeX (`pdflatex`, `lualatex`, `xelatex`)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23957) and for [setting up font size 8.5pt](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/how-to-specify-font-size-less-than-10pt-or-more-than-12pt) with LaTeX or are you searching how to setup the font and font size of the editor?

Answer (score 4):

The [`scrartcl`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/koma-script/scrguien.pdf) class can work with any font but you have to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=8.5pt,DIV=calc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\begin{document}
This should be in 8.5pt font.
\end{document}
```

Comment: There are packages to support Arial like fonts using `pdflatex`, e.g., `uarial` for the ugly URW A030 (Arial).

Comment: @Schweinebacke: With 8.5pt size?

Comment: `uarial` provides scalable font setup. KOMA-Script classes (and also `memoir`) do not depend on XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. So: Yes.

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
% The command below will automatically compile your document with XeLaTeX, which is needed if you want to use Arial or any font which is installed on your system.
% !TeX program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} % Needed to run XeLaTeX
\usepackage{lipsum} % (Use for dummy (Lorem ipsum) text
\setmainfont{Arial}

\usepackage[9pt]{extsizes} % The sizes available are 8pt, 9pt, 10pt, 11pt, 12pt, 14pt, 17pt, and 20pt

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}.
```