# Code not working on overleaf

Tags: fonts

I am using overleaf but this code is not working can you help?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{uarial}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: The error that Overleaf shows me is "File uarial.sty not found".  What is that file, and what should it be doing?  Without that line, your file example compiles just fine.

Comment: in texlive 2021 I get `! LaTeX Error: File \`uarial.sty' not found.`

Comment: I guess [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64134098/14891939) it is explained and solved.

Comment: What happens, if you delete or comment out '\usepackage{uarial}' ?

Comment: If I remember correctly, there used to be a font package called `uarial`, which implemented a clone of the Arial font face which, in turn, is a (weak) clone of the Helvetica font face. Unless you have to submit your document to a font freak who (a) can discern the mostly very subtle differences between Helvetica and Arial and (b) cares deeply that Arial rather than Helvetica should be employed, just replace `\usepackage{uarial}` with `\usepackage{helvet}` and live happily ever after.

Comment: See [https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23957](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23957/110998) for suggegtions how to either install `uarial` (manual installation) or to replace it by other, similar fonts.

Comment: @Onur Gürdoğan How do i add this https://ctan.crest.fr/tex-archive/fonts/urw/arial/latex/uarial.sty to my document? I get an error when adding.

Comment: @gernot I downloaded the setup file, but it wasn't seen as a setup file on my computer, so I couldn't install it.

Comment: @MS-SPO  When i delete file opens but without uarial:)

Comment: Some of the solutions may be tricky to use on Overleaf, like when trying to install fonts. Ask the staff at Overleaf how to set the paths. Or better, switch to fonts supported by standard TeX distributions. Or install TeX locally.

Comment: why do you need urarial which is not supported in standard tex distributions rather than use one of the Arial/Helvetica clones that is supported?

Comment: @gernot thanks.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Arial doesn't work :( I am getting error like uarial

Comment: did you use `helvet` as mico suggested or `tgheros` package

Comment: yes so i used..

Comment: so we can close this now?

Comment: of course. thank you