# Arial font, and non-scalable mathcal fonts

Tags: fonts, math-fonts, arial

I have to use the Arial font and I do that as follows (Helvetica is close to Arial):

```
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv} % Helvetica
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv} % Helvetica
```

The other solution I have found is to use the commands:

```
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

Both work and as far as I can see, both solutions look the same. I use the following packages for math fonts because it looks nice with Arial fonts:

```
\usepackage[amsthm,mathsfit]{libertinust1math}
```

I want to modify some font sizes as follows (it looks nice with 1, but it looks nicer with 1.2):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\LinuxLibertineT@scale}{1.2}
\makeatother
```

The issue I have is that the `\mathcal` fonts are apparently not scalable as far as I understand the problem. Is there any way to overcome the problem ? (I know nothing about fonts sorry)

Comment: This isn't Arial font. This is a free substitution of Helvetica. The fonts Helvetica and Arial differ.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your posting -- specifically, of replacing all instances of "Aria" with "Arial". Incidentally, if you want 12pt instead of 10pt as the default document font size, just specify `12pt` as one of the optional arguments of the `\documentclass` instruction: `\documentclass[12pt,...]{...}`.

Comment: @wipet - While technically true, your observation that Helvetica and Arial differ is probably less than helpful for someone who has stated up front to "know nothing about fonts". Arial is a drop-in replacement clone of Helvetica. If not for the shapes of the "R", "t" and "a" glyphs, even many real font experts have to slow down and take a rather close look before being able to tell any difference between Helvetica and Arial. The OP's issue is *not* with Helvetica not being identical to Arial; instead, it's with an unsuitable math font.

Comment: @wipet I knew that Arial and Helvetica differ slightly :-). But it does not seem to be possible to install Arial in my Ubuntu computer (after browsing this forum) without a headache and Helvetica is close enough to Arial I think.

Comment: You don't need to install Arial, just don't call Helvetica Arial.

Comment: @wipet Okay but I just copy-pasted answers from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23957.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv} % Arial` has absurd comment, should be `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv} % Helvetica`. And the answers you pointed include the correct notices about Helvetica.

Comment: @wipet Did you mean a substitute **for** Helvetica rather than **of**? None of this is relevant, but if you want strict accuracy, Helvetica isn't a free substitute for Arial and predates it. Whether Arial is a 'rip off' of Helvetica or an inspired descendant is controversial, but Helvetica was certainly first and commercial. That said, `phv` is no more Helvetica than it is Arial. Which font you get is extent system-dependent, but most people will get e.g. URW NimbusSanL  (`uhv`) and not Adobe Helvetica (`phv`). It's true the metrics may differ from those of Arial (but not Helvetica).

Comment: @cfr My text "it is free substitution of Helvetica" meant that "phv" is linked to a free substitution NimbusSansL of Helvetica without such detail. I am saying that Arial differs from Helvetica, nothing more. Helvetica was designed by Eduard Hoffman in 1957 when phototypesetter technology was. There is many re-implementaion of Helvetica for computers. Non-free Helvetica from Adobe, free NimbusSanL from URW, Heros from TeXGyre and maybe others. I didn't want to dive to such details. I only say that Helvetica isn't Arial which was designed by Robin Nicholas in 1982 and used by Microsoft.

Comment: @wipet Indeed. That's what I meant by the 'of'/'for' thing ;).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `libertinust1math.sty`, `\mathcal` font is stixcal.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[amsthm,mathsfit]{libertinust1math}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\LinuxLibertineT@scale}{1.2}
\makeatother
\DeclareFontShape{U}{stixcal}{m}{n} {<->s*[1.2]stix-mathcal}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{stixcal}{b}{n} {<->s*[1.2]stix-mathcal-bold}{}
\begin{document}
test $t$ $\mathcal{A}$
\end{document}
```

[image]